# Path2D.addPath got removed?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, path-2d

I have been working with `Path2D` for a while, but now it seems like it's function `Path2D.addPath(path, matrix?)` got removed (at least in chrome).

Is there actually any replacement?
Is it permanent, or just a mistake on browser part?

Comment: Note that it is available under the *chrome:flags* => *experimental Canvas features*.

Answer (score 1):

This is the information on addPath from MDN (and shameless plug):

["`addPath`"](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Path2D/addPath) (NOTE: EXPERIMENTAL, on standard track)

```
  DESKTOP:
  Chrome  | Firefox | Edge    | IE      | Opera   | Safari
  --------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------
    Yes   |    34   |     -   |     -   |   Yes   |   Yes

  MOBILE:
  Android | Chrome  | Edge    | Firefox | Opera   | Safari
  --------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------
    Yes   |   Yes   |     -   |    34   |   Yes   |   Yes

Data from MDN - 'npm i -g mdncomp' by K3N / epistemex.com (c) 2018.
```

But you're right, it seem to be gone from the prototype in current Chrome version(s). My guess is that it is related to [changing the API](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/mhjb3Em8H0A) to use DOMMatrix instead of SVGMatrix, though by now that should be in place and there is currently nothing to be found at [bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=path2D&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&x=m&y=releaseblock&cells=ids). In any case, we're left to wait for an update.

There are no good workarounds for this besides from adding the path directly to context. If the scope is limited you might be able to use a secondary context and draw the paths back in from there. A polyfill approach will be extensive as you would need to rebuild the entire Path2D API to get access to the path information.

Comment: I have looked up the MDN, I as of right now I am thinking about posting it as chromium bug... I would understand them removing it completely, but as path don't have `beginPath` function, they are useless for more complex shapes... Also, I would thing they might remove it as whole and not just this part...